# Update dotnet cli in Mac OSX

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-cli, .net-core

Im'm trying to upgrade my dotnet cli. I have installed in my Mac (OS El Capitan) from the official [link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos).

But when I try to view the version with this code:

> dotnet --version

My output:

> 1.0.0-preview2-003121

How can I upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version 1.0.0-preview2-003121 of the .Net CLI is currently the latest released version. So there is no newer released version to upgrade to.

You *could* upgrade to the latest build from [the dotnet/cli repo](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/), but you probably shouldn't, since that's not a released version.

Comment: So does that mean you can not run a csproj core app on OS X yet? Only project.json based projects?

Comment: @RyanMendoza You can, if you install [RC4](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/rc4-download.md) of the SDK, or the daily build.

Answer (score 2):

To update from 2.0.3 to 2.1.4 I simply downloaded the installer from Microsoft's website and then ran the installer.

`https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/5/115B762D-2B41-4AF3-9A63-92D9680B9409/dotnet-sdk-2.1.4-osx-gs-x64.pkg

I had a Terminal window open, and when I did a `dotnet --version` before and after running the installer, the correct version was output to the console. I did not have to restart my terminal window even.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has done a good job at packaging the SDK and CLI together. See either their main dotnetcore website or go to their [git](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md)